# Hash computation in Google safe browsing V2 implementation

Tags: api, sha256, safe-browsing

I am trying to test my implementation of the google safe browsing api version 2. 
To test a part of my code that sends requests for full hashes for a given prefix, I captured a short session of traffic where I visited a known currently blacklisted url "utfvq.portrelay.com" and firefox sent a request to google for full hashes and google responded with a list of hashes.

The prefixes firefox sent are(Hex encoded) : `2e2e372e,2e26382e,2e2e382e,6545382e`

The 4 matching full hashes it received are :

```
2e26382e2e2e436d2e2e2e2e322e3b2e2e2e2e2e4a2e2e2e7b2e2e2e6a492e2e
6545382e2e2a5b792e652e2e2e2e2e2e2e2e70442e7d2e2e2e222e2e502e2e2e
2e2e382e6c36252e2e522e2e592e2e2e2e2e3f592e2e2e782e2e572e4e2e2e2e
2e2e372e2e2e2e2e55682e542e51622e552e2e68352e2e2e2e2e2e2e2ed2755
```

In my implementation however, the hash prefixes I generate do not seem to match the hash prefixes that firefox sent. Hence, I am not getting any full hash matches in my client.

I have followed googles description of the API closely and made sure the previous steps such as url canonicalization are implemented properly.

The url, SHA256 hashes I get are

utfvq.portrelay.com/  : `5c2383012676e63656c13167e1cc4f55309c4e1b73c22556e36ec1487e8b8697`

portrelay.com/ : `842638fe92ee436da7808d0232d03bcaa0f5c8b64ad5eee97bf28dbb6a49f8ae`

Can some one point out why the hashes do not match. I have followed the API guide to the best of my knowledge. Is there some implementation detail I am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a basic character encoding error on my part.

The SHA hashes I compute in my code are correct. The way I looked at the hashes that firefox sent was wrong. I copied the characters from a text file where it stored any byte not with in regular ascii range as a dot(.). Then I converted these to Hex values which is a kind of "lossy" encoding. This is why there were so many "2e" hex chars in the hashes. Now I am using just the original bytes and they match.

Comment: Hey would you be able to tell me how to generate hash prefix of a URL string in detail?